How can I serialize a complex type such as Schema.DescribeSObjectResult?
Let's say we have
 public static void performMigration(Boolean isTest) {
    List<Map<Id, Id[]>> tempo = new List<Map<Id, Id[]>>(); 
    for(Migration_Tools_Mapping__mdt victim : [SELECT 
            source_id__c, 
            target_id__c 
        FROM Migration_Tools_Mapping__mdt 
        WHERE is_single__c = false and is_test__c = :isTest]) {
            tempo.add(new Map<Id,Id[]>{victim.source_id__c => new Id[]{victim.target_id__c}});
        }
        MigrationToolsMainQueueable mtq = new MigrationToolsMainQueueable(tempo, 0, true);
        system.enqueueJob(mtq, 0);
    //run(tempo);
}

but everytime i try to run it i got an error

"Not Serializable: Map<String,Schema.DescribeSObjectResult>"

is it a way to resolve it somehow?

Sounds like you need to examine the MigrationToolsMainQueueable. I presume an instance of that is being serialised by the queuable framework, and it has a class attribute that are of that unserializable type.

I suspect your MigrationToolsMainQueueable class has a non-static attribute of type DescribeSObjectResult. You need to remove this, moving getting the describe at the start of your execute method as a local variable.

correct Phil W. i made it static and it works now

Yes. Don't serialize the Schema.DescribeSObjectResult type. To solve this, you put the necessary fields/information into another map, like in a Map<String, Object>, and serialize that object instead.
Iterate the type and build a list of maps (as if they were objects of a class) or do have a custom class to work this data with.
// map example
List<Map<String, Object>> items = new List<Map<String, Object>>();

for (Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dr : query) {
    items.add(new Map<String, Object>{
        'label' => dr.getLabel()
    });
}

// custom type example
List<MyDescribeResult> items = new List<MyDescribeResult>();

for (Schema.DescribeSObjectResult dr : query) {
    // like this or...
    items.add(new MyDescribeResult(dr.getLabel()));

    // In this second example you can also construct
    // the type and assign the variables later.
    // It doesn't really matter.

    MyDescribeResult myInstance = new MyDescribeResult();
    myInstance.label = dr.getLabel();

    items.add(myInstance);
}

public class MyDescribeResult {
    public String label;

    public MyDescribeResult() {
    }

    public MyDescribeResult(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}


but Renato i'm just trying to pass List<Map<Id, Id[]>> to queueable. Where did salesforce find Schema.DescribeSObjectResult? maybe there is a need to cast entries from new Id[]{victim.target_id__c} to Id?

It probably comes from your custom metadata type, which references an entity (an object or field) in one of the fields it has. Are you sure the error is coming from a line on that code? Is it from the System.enqueueJob line?

correct, just right from system.enqueueJob line

Renato, mdt has the only 2 ids as a custom fields
